# Как остановить анимацию SVG при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: css, html5, svg, анимация, css-animation

У меня есть SVG-анимация, и я пытаюсь понять, как остановить и заморозить SVG в поле зрения сразу после завершения анимационной последовательности. Таким образом, логотип остается на странице до обновления следующей страницы и т.д.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u410bjyk/)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.pin__group {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 30px 30px;
          transform-origin: 30px 30px;
  -webkit-animation: group-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: group-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__grayGroup {
  -webkit-animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__square {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 240, 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  -webkit-animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__line {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 60, 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: 60;
}
.pin__line-1 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
}
.pin__line-2 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
}
.pin__line-3 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleBig {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 188.522, 188.522;
  stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  -webkit-animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleSmall {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__outer {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 201.391, 201.391;
  stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  -webkit-animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__inner {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <svg class="pin" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1">
  <g class="pin__group">
    <g class="pin__grayGroup">
      <path class="pin__square" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,0 0,60 60,60 60,0z"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M15,0 15,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M30,0 30,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,0 45,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,45 60,45"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,30 60,30"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,15 60,15"/>
      <path class="pin__circleBig" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M60,30 a30,30 0 0,1 -60,0 a30,30 0 0,1 60,0"/>
      <path class="pin__circleSmall" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
    <g class="pin__greenGroup">
      <path class="pin__outer" stroke-width="2" d="M30,0 a30,30 0 0,1 30,30 L60,60 30,60 a30,30 0 0,1 0,-60"/>
      <path class="pin__inner" stroke-width="2" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Я  могу удалить свойство `infinite`, чтобы запустить анимацию один раз, но вопрос в том, как  можно остановить анимацию сразу после нажатия кнопки?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46672625/7394871

Comment: а как тогда запустить анимацию после stop ?

Comment: @MaximLensky В вопросе это не требовалось, но смотри код ответа - остановка - подключение класса .`stop`. Следовательно пуск - удаление класса .`stop`

Comment: а точно...просто удалить class ....спсибо

Answer (score 8):

Вы можете приостановить CSS-анимацию, используя:

```
animation-play-state: paused;
```

Я добавил в ваш пример кнопку, которая позволяет вам остановить анимацию в любой момент.

```js
function stop() {
  $(".pin__group, .pin__grayGroup, .pin__square, .pin__line-1, .pin__line-2, .pin__line-3, .pin__circleBig, .pin__circleSmall, .pin__outer, .pin__inner").addClass("stop");
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.pin__group {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 30px 30px;
          transform-origin: 30px 30px;
  -webkit-animation: group-anim 8s 1s forwards;
          animation: group-anim 8s 1s forwards;
}
.pin__grayGroup {
  -webkit-animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: gray-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__square {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 240, 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  -webkit-animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: square-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__line {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 60, 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: 60;
}
.pin__line-1 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.6s infinite;
}
.pin__line-2 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 0.8s infinite;
}
.pin__line-3 {
  -webkit-animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: line-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleBig {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 188.522, 188.522;
  stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  -webkit-animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: bigCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__circleSmall {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: smallCircle-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__outer {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 201.391, 201.391;
  stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  -webkit-animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: outer-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}
.pin__inner {
  stroke: #00CD73;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 94.261, 94.261;
  stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  -webkit-animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
          animation: inner-anim 8s 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes square-anim {
  15% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes line-anim {
  23% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bigCircle-anim {
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes smallCircle-anim {
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  53% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes group-anim {
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  94% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@keyframes outer-anim {
  61% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 201.391;
  }
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #00CD73;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@keyframes inner-anim {
  71% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 94.261;
  }
  79% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  94% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
}
@keyframes gray-anim {
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  79% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
}

.stop {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="pin" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1">
  <g class="pin__group">
    <g class="pin__grayGroup">
      <path class="pin__square" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,0 0,60 60,60 60,0z"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M15,0 15,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M30,0 30,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,0 45,60"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,45 60,45"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,30 60,30"/>
      <path class="pin__line pin__line-3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M0,15 60,15"/>
      <path class="pin__circleBig" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M60,30 a30,30 0 0,1 -60,0 a30,30 0 0,1 60,0"/>
      <path class="pin__circleSmall" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
    <g class="pin__greenGroup">
      <path class="pin__outer" stroke-width="2" d="M30,0 a30,30 0 0,1 30,30 L60,60 30,60 a30,30 0 0,1 0,-60"/>
      <path class="pin__inner" stroke-width="2" d="M45,30 a15,15 0 0,1 -30,0 a15,15 0 0,1 30,0"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```